# Swift UIPageControl not showing dots

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIPageControl` which is updated based on a UIScrollView (**numberOfPages** and **currentPage**).

It has black and gray colors for current page and other pages dots, respectively.
When loading the app for the first time, only the current page dot shows up, not the gray ones. After scrolling the view, the gray dots appear and everything is fine.

What could be causing this?

**Update:**
So, I set the UIPageControl to have 3 pages

`self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3`

and I set the current page

`self.pageControl.currentPage = 0`

The page control should present like o x x (o - selected, x - unselected), but it actually shows only the current page: o

Then I did this:

```
for i in 0..<(self.pageControl.numberOfPages) {
   self.pageControl.currentPage = i
}
self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
```

which solves the problem. Obvisously, it's an hack.

So I wonder if this a bug with the page control or something that I'm doing wrong..

Comment: any help? Can't figure out the problem

Comment: Why the downvote, can't really understand...

Comment: did you find solution? I also have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide us more information. As per your short description i can give you below suggestions.
1. Check page control frame.
2. Change your de-select state page dot color. It might be matching with your first page’s background color so that’s why it’s not showing.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution I found is as below.

```
// lets set current page from 0 to N number of items
for i in 0..<adsArray.count {
    pageControl.currentPage = i
}

// set current page back to 0 as we need
pageControl.currentPage = 0
```